# xcode 4.6 ad hoc provision for mac OS X app, app running on devices not listed in profile

Tags: xcode, macos, beta-testing

I am attempting to get a **beta copy** of my `OS X` **app** out to testers via `ad hoc` distribution. There is quite a bit of discussion around this, but not much on **Mac applications**.

I have added the desired computer `UUID's` and generated a provision profile. The build is signed with my **developer certificate**. The built app launches and runs not only on my **Mac**, but also on a second test machine. Neither computer has the provision profile installed.

I'm not sure if it should run outside of `Xcode` on my machine, but obviously I can't send out a copy that is not effectively protected by the provision profile.

How can I check that the build settings & code signing are correct for `ad hoc` distribution?